# Error in creating csv out of an excel file read by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in an excel file and then spitting out a sheet from that excel file, both using pandas. However, I am getting an error as follows:

```
try:
    fao_file = pd.ExcelFile('FAO_Crops_area_harvested_Data.xlsx')
except:
    logging.info('Error reading excel file on FAO data')

df = fao_file.parse('Production_Crops_E_All_Data.csv')
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf4' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The excel file is available here: 
https://umd.box.com/s/73dqgf8npqquq3icw6w2z8xq73vob3me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Python 2.  Try changing

```
 df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

to

```
 df.to_csv('out.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```